# Sum of averages raw query

Tags: mysql, django, query-optimization

I have the following code that I have to optimize:

These are the models:

```
class Question(models.Model):   
   question_id = models.CharField(max_length=20) 
   label = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Question')    

class Property(models.Model):    
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Response(models.Model):
   question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)   
   submit_date = models.DateTimeField()
   score = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
   is_null = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   ignore = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   property = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  
class Plan(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question, through='PlanQuestion')
   start_date = models.DateField(null=True)
   completion_date = models.DateField(null=True)

class PlanQuestion(models.Model):
   question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I first iterate over the plans then plan questions like this:

```
plans = Plan.objects.filter(
    start_date__isnull=False, completion_date__isnull=False
)

for plan in plans:
    plan_questions = plan.questions.through.objects.filter(plan=plan)
    for plan_question in plan_questions:
       # run the below query for each plan_question here
```

In the above code for each plan question this query is run to calculate the average of score:

```
SELECT AVG(score) AS average_score
FROM Response WHERE question_id=%(question_id)s 
AND DATE(submit_date) >= %(stard_date)s AND DATE(submit_date) <= %(end_date)s
```

The problem is that:

If let us say Plan1 has 5 questions:

P1 => Avg(Q1) + Avg(Q2) + Avg(Q3) + Avg(Q4) + Avg(Q5)

The query is run for each question which calculates the average score for each response (one question can have many responses) so for P1, 5 queries are run, and let us say it takes 0.5 seconds to execute one query then it would take 2.5 seconds (5 * 0.5) to run 5 queries for one plan. Now If we increase the number of Plans each having 5 questions then it would increase the time exponentially.

I want a way to reduce the number of these queries so that for each question I don't have to run queries separately. How to combine all the queries of question in one query ?. Maybe I can use union but I don't get how would I write a single query using that or maybe there might be a better solution than a union.

I also tried to add `prefech_related` but that did no improvement.

**Edit:**

Create Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `Response` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `Response_25110688` (`question_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `question_id_refs_id_2dd82bdb` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `Question` (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=157533450 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `Question` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `label` varchar(255) NOT NULL,   
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=353 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `Plan` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `completion_date` date DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=687 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `PlanQuestion` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `plan_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `PlanQuestion_plan_id_de8df699_fk_Plan_id` (`plan_id`),
 KEY `PlanQuestion_question_id_49c10d5b_fk_Question_id` (`question_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `PlanQuestion_plan_id_de8df699_fk_Plan_id` FOREIGN KEY (`plan_id`) REFERENCES `Plan` (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `PlanQuestion_question_id_49c10d5b_fk_Question_id` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `Question` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2130 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `Property` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=188651 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

<s>Here is the full query:</s>

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS count, AVG(int_val) AS int_average
FROM Response WHERE question_id=%(question_id)s 
AND property_id=%(property_id)s and is_null=0 
AND Response.ignore=0 AND DATE(submit_date) >= %(stard_date)s 
AND DATE(submit_date) <= %(end_date)s
```

Comment: Show us the SQL code -- it would be easier for me to make performance suggestions from that point of view.  Also provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the relevant tables.

Comment: I have given SQL for calculating score. What do you mean by create table i cannot make database change only code and query optimization as that is production code. I just want SQL to calculate scores of all the plan questions (not like querying them individually which is currently happening)

Comment: Whether or not you can change the schema, It helps us to know what the datatypes are, the engine, the index(es), etc.

Comment: @RickJames sure let me update question with that.

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but tryng to optimize queries without information about the tables and indexes is, at best, a waste of the only irreplaceable kind of time: yours and mine.  To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need more information. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: Hi @Ahtisham, I have read your question multiple times but It's not understandable. Please update your question. 

Eg.., How do I get an average int_val field for a question in the Response model with the start and end date based on the Plan model.

If you explain It with some examples people might help you solve your doubts.

Comment: @O.Jones Please check to update the question. Sorry, I am new to MySQL. I have removed the constraints as there are a lot of columns that are not relevant to the problem.

Comment: Information hiding is a valid objective of object-oriented programming. But hiding the "constraints" as you call them, or "indexes" as the people who are NOT new to SQL call them, makes it impossible to do anything worthwhile when trying to optimize data access. It's just the way SQL works, and has worked for several decades.

Comment: (What is the relevance of `prefech_related`?)

Comment: @RickJames you mean what that is ? If yes it does the joins on many to many relation in django using its orm i added that to plan_questions and plan but they did no improvement to the speed: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related

Comment: @Ahtisham - `JOINs` add another dimension to optimization.  We need to see the whole query.

Comment: (I don't speak DJango; "prefetching" sounds like an optimization that will sometimes slow things down.  Please check where it helps _or hurts_ performance.)

Comment: @O.Jones Please check my question I have updated it.

Comment: @goku10 I have updated my question please check

Answer (score 1):

This does not make a lot of sense:

```
SELECT  id, COUNT(*) AS count, AVG(int_val) AS int_average
    FROM  Response
    WHERE  question_id=%(question_id)s
      AND  DATE(submit_date) >= %(stard_date)s
      AND  DATE(submit_date) <= %(end_date)s
```

Without a `GROUP BY`, the `COUNT` and `AVG` will be totals for the one "question_id".  But then if there is a different `id` for each row, which `id` are you hoping for?

OK, assuming `id` is removed, it needs this composite index with the columns in this order:

```
INDEX(question_id, submit_date)
```

Meanwhile, remove `INDEX(question_id)` because it will be in the way.

Sorry, but sometimes performance *requires* changes.

Secondly...  "for plan_question in plan_questions" implies that you want that to be run for every "question"?

Then get rid of the loop and do all the work at the same time:

```
SELECT  question_id, COUNT(*) AS count, AVG(int_val) AS int_average
    FROM  Response
    WHERE  DATE(submit_date) >= %(start_date)s
      AND  DATE(submit_date) <= %(end_date)s 
    GROUP BY question_id
```

This will return one row per question; *then* you can loop through the resultset to deliver the output.

Good news:  Even if you don't add the above index, this will work better than what you have now.

Also... `cur_date = datetime.now().date()` could be removed from the app code; instead, use simply `CURDATE()` in  SQL to get just the date or `NOW()` to get the date+time.

**Indexing** Getting rid of "for plan_question in plan_questions" will be the biggest benefit.  The query (as I wrote it) already benefits from the index on `question_id`.  However, adding `INDEX(submit_date)` might run faster if the date range is narrow.

If there are other clauses in the `WHERE`, we need to see them.  There may be other indexes to suggest.

**More**

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM response
    -- (and not JOINing to any other tables)
    GROUP BY id;
```

This query always has a `count` of 1 because each `id` occurs in `response` exactly once.

```
SELECT 
    -- (without id)
    COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM response
    -- (and not JOINing to any other tables)
    -- (without GROUP BY)
    ;
```

This query always returns exactly 1 row.

**Still More**

Based on

```
WHERE question_id=%(question_id)s 
AND property_id=%(property_id)s and is_null=0 
AND Response.ignore=0 AND DATE(submit_date)...
```

you need

```
INDEX(question_id, property_id, is_null, ignore)
```

and drop INDEX(question_id).

But...  My statement about doing a single query instead of an app loop still stands.

**JOINing to Plan**

```
SELECT  r.question_id,
        COUNT(*) AS count,
        AVG(r.int_val) AS int_average,
        p.plan  -- perhaps you want to say which "plan" is involved?
    FROM  Plans AS p
    JOIN  PLanQuestions AS pq  ON pq.plan_id = p.plan_id
    JOIN  Responses AS r       ON r.question_id = pq.question_id
    WHERE p.... -- optionally filter on which plans to include
      AND pq.... -- optionally filter on the other columns in pq
      AND r.... -- optionally filter on which responses to include
    ORDER BY ... -- optionally sort the results by any column(s) in any table(s)
```

And remove the two single-column indexes in `PlanQuestions`, replacing them by two 2-column indexes:

```
INDEX(plan_id, question_id),
INDEX(question_id, plan_id)
      AND  DATE(submit_date) <= %(end_date)s 
    GROUP BY question_id
```

**Sargable**

`DATE(submit_date) >= "..."` is "not sargable"  This means that an index involving `col` cannot help with the test.  Since `submit_date` is of datatype `DATE`, this is semantically identical *and faster*:

```
submit_date >= "..."
```

Comment: @Ahtisham - Sounds like it needs to `JOIN` to `Plans`?

Comment: Yes i think i need to do joins on plan and maybe plan questions too but don't get how to create a query with joins for that.

Comment: I got where you get confused about the query it was my bad I have forgotten to add the `question_id` column in the `Question` table. The `question_id` is a character field. Please check my question updated it.

Comment: Which plans?  Any plan in `Plans`?  Or maybe there is a `WHERE` clause for filtering?

Comment: Please check again added it

Comment: @Ahtisham - I added a couple more sections.  (Again, I cannot say how to map that back to Django.)

Comment: @Ahtisham - Seems like `question_id` should be the `PRIMARY KEY` in `Questions`??  Or at least indexed?  If the query also needs to display `Questions.label`, then another `JOIN` is needed in the query.

Comment: No, I don't think I would need a label as I only have to compute the average of each question. And no `question_id` cannot be the primary key the reason being it represents the type of survey plus `Question` table's id for example: if the survey is resident survey then question_id would start with 'R' and then the id of `Question` so if the id of question is 1 it would be 'R1' for example. Primary Key is the id column of Question table. And yes I think it needs to be indexed.

Comment: Also, the Join you posted in your answer doesn't that calculate average of all the questions I would mention in the query in where caluse as a whole ? but I think i want to calculate the Average of each question and then sum their averages.

Comment: @Ahtisham - Oops -- One must be careful to have the right tables Joined to get the right counts, etc.  That can lead to being forced to do some Joins _after_ the Grouping and aggregates.

Comment: @Ahtisham - At this point, I don't understand the business logic and schema design enough to help you other than to suggest things.  You should digest the info and revise your schema and code.  (If necessary, _then_ start a _new_ question with the _new_ schema and query.  This Q&A is getting to long for anyone else to read.)

Comment: I think I just need a single query that would compute the sum of averages of questions. Maybe we can use UNION. I don't think I would ask it again now I am tired of people downvote without giving a reason.  Maybe will ask it in reddit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241565/discussion-between-ahtisham-and-rick-james).